# Optimize function slicing numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I have the following function, which takes a numpy array of floats and an integer as its arguments. Each row in the array 'counts' is the result of some experiment, and I want to randomly draw a list of the experiments and add them up, then repeat this process to create lots of samples groups.

```
def my_function(counts,nSamples):
    ''' Create multiple randomly drawn (with replacement)
        samples from the raw data '''
    nSat,nRegions = counts.shape
    sampleData = np.zeros((nSamples,nRegions))
    for i in range(nSamples):
        rc = np.random.randint(0,nSat,size=nSat)
        sampleData[i] = counts[rc].sum(axis=0)
    return sampleData
```

This function seems quite slow, typically counts has around 100,000 rows (and 4 columns) and nSamples is around 2000. I have tried using numba and implicit for loops to try and speed up this code with no success.
What are some other methods to try and increase the speed?

I have run cProfile on the function and got the following output.

8005 function calls in 60.208 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

    1    0.000    0.000   60.208   60.208 <string>:1(<module>)

 2000    0.010    0.000   13.306    0.007 _methods.py:31(_sum)

    1   40.950   40.950   60.208   60.208 optimize_bootstrap.py:25(bootstrap)

    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}

 2000    5.938    0.003    5.938    0.003 {method 'randint' of 'mtrand.RandomState' objects}

 2000   13.296    0.007   13.296    0.007 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}

 2000    0.015    0.000   13.321    0.007 {method 'sum' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}

    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.zeros}

    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that

`rc = np.random.randint(0,nSat,size=nSat)`

is what you want, instead of `size=someconstant`? Otherwise you're summing over all the rows with many repeats.

---

**edit**
does it help to replace the slicing altogether with a matrix product:

`rcvec=np.zeros(nSat,np.int)
for i in rc:
    rcvec[i]+=1
sampleData[i] = rcvec.dot(counts)`

(maybe there is a function in numpy that can give you rcvec faster)

Comment: Yes, I'm doing a bootstrap analysis

Comment: I see. does the above help?

Answer (score 0):

Simply generate all indices in one go with a `2D` size for `np.random.randint`, use those to index into `counts` array and then sum along the first axis, just like you were doing with the loopy one.

Thus, one vectorized way and as such faster one, would be like so -

```
RC = np.random.randint(0,nSat,size=(nSat, nSamples))
sampleData_out = counts[RC].sum(axis=0)
```